# Random text in javaScript

Tags: javascript, function, random, text

I'am trying to make a random function that every time that apper, apper with a different text

I have done a array like this:

```js
let text = ['Oh Noo!!', 'You lost!', 'Try a next time!!'];
```

and here is the function:

```js
function drawGameEnd() {
  
  if (gameOver || gameWin) {
      text = "Congrats!";
    if (gameOver) {
      text = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "#2215d6";
    ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.height / 4, canvas.width, 190); //canvas text gradientes

    ctx.font = "28px Comic Neue";
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0", "#fff");

    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillText(text, 20, canvas.height / 2.2);

  }
}
```

But when a run it, it only show one letter of the word...
How can i fix it?

Comment: You are reusing the variable text. In the second if condition, text isn't an array, it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you defined text as a string

```js
const texts = ['Oh Noo!!', 'You lost!', 'Try a next time!!'];;
text = texts[Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length)];
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are reassigning the variable `text` which holds your array of text options, to hold the single word you chose. The next time `drawGameEnd` is called, rather than selecting a single word in the original array, it selects a single letter from that word.

Only reason this bug didn't result in an error is because a string is kinda like an array of characters, so syntactically it checks out for the first two times `drawGameEnd` is called... untyped JS is wild.

Comment: I kinda can see what you mean, but how can i fix it? To instead return just one letter, return the full word?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a variable called `text` and set it to an array of strings:

```
let text = ['Oh Noo!!', 'You lost!', 'Try a next time!!'];
```

Then what do you do with `text`?...

```
text = "Congrats!";
```

or:

```
text = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
```

Now it's not an array.  Now it's a string.  The array is gone.  (And, later, if you treat a string as an array then it's an array of characters.)

The lesson here is that you shouldn't try to store everything in the same variable.  Because once you do, you overwrite whatever was previously stored in that variable.

Use different variable names.  And convey information about what the variable is in those names.  For example:

```
let textOptions = ['Oh Noo!!', 'You lost!', 'Try a next time!!'];
let text = '';
```

and:

```
if (gameOver || gameWin) {
  text = "Congrats!";
  if (gameOver) {
    text = textOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * textOptions.length)];
  }
  //...
```

Comment: *super worked for me*, so the problem is that i was using the same variable in differents points of the code, changing her value?? i thought this was ok...

Comment: @Bumboobee: It is okay to change the value of a variable, *if* that's what you want to do.  Just keep in mind that once you've changed it, it's now different.  So *if* you want to overwrite the array and lose it, that's up to you.

Comment: @Bumboobee incidentally this is why you may want to see about using typescript instead of javascript, it will help you avoid making these kinds of mistakes